# Android 50mb limit hosting a unity view

Tags: android, unity-game-engine

My app is not totally made with unity, unity3D is just a part of it that runs in a subview.

The app is 90Mb in total. I see 2 solutions to the 50Mb problem :

- ask unity to generate the split for me. unfortunately this seems to work only for app completely done with unity
- extension files. This seems to work fine with sqlite dbs or image files because if you know the location you open such files easily. Unfortunately in unity there are some special folders (`assets/bin` and `src/main/jniLibs`) and I don't have control over the location of those when I do `unity.play()`

Any idea ?

Comment: My App (not using Unity) also has a lot of required data, so I hosted most of the files on a secure webspace and made the App download all the required content after the first installation. Maybe this is also an option for you.

Comment: @Westranger more or less what you do with **expansion files**.

Comment: @Westranger this is point 2 of my question. can I download content and place it in src/main/... ? I doubt so

Comment: @Thomas I doubt so too. I havn't tried this yet

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For those that can help, using the `.obb` generated from unity worked.

This is the unity snippet of the script I run before generating an apk for Google Play

```
mv UnityProject/assets/bin/ app/src/main/assets/
mv UnityProject/libs/unity-classes.jar app/libs/
rm -rf app/src/main/jniLibs/armeabi-v7a
mv UnityProject/libs/armeabi-v7a/ app/src/main/jniLibs
```

Placing files this way will make the Android app work with the expansion file provided by Unity.